# Angular2 highchart-more

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to create  spider chart. I use [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCbX8kxvhCDxww3HWiG5?p=preview)

But I get [image: this error]

```
`import { CHART_DIRECTIVES, Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts'; 
 import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';   
 HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
 ...`
```

Comment: but your link works.. and your code in your question is too minimal to give it any proper answer

Comment: I copied  the code from  that example and paste it to may  local project. I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-more and  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts.But at my  project the same doesent work.

Comment: Please provide more code, especially the fragment where `each` property is read/called on an object. The object on which the property is accessed is undefined (as the error says) so maybe your data is not yet resolved.

Comment: This is my imports :import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES, Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import HighchartsMore   from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);

Comment: in constructor I added this one : constructor() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'line',
        polar: true
      },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
      }]
    };
  }

Comment: I add in template next: <chart [options]="options"></chart>

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this, its worked for me i am trying to get the gauge chart..this worked for me, and set polar for you to get spider chart

declaration chart module like this

```
import { ChartModule} from 'angular2-highcharts';

imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ChartModule,
    ....
  ],
```

and on export class page where you want to call the highchart

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);

export class component {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  this.chart1 = {
     chart:{
     polar: true,
     type:'line',
     backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
     },
      title : { text : 'simple chart' },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
      }]
    };
 }
chart1: Object;
```

html code

```
<chart [options]="chart1" > </chart>
```

Comment: This import: `import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';` gives me the error:  `Module '"c:/pdws-view-v2/node_modules/@types/highcharts/highcharts-more"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.` Any ideas?